# How to Enable Local Storage in Web Application Swift View

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am developing a small app in Swift3 for iOS, I previously developed it for Android where I had a problem that is replicated here. It happens that I have a webview where you have to upload some videos, youtube videos are reproduced without problems (both Android and iOS), the problem arises when you want to play a video for example with JWPlayer, the problem I had in Android Was that the property was not enabled to write to disk and the solution was as follows:

```
final WebView myBrowser;
myBrowser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

What would be the solution for Swift3?

I found this solution:

```
var prefs: WebPreferences? = webView.prefereces
prefs?._setLocalStorageDatabasePath("~/Library/Application Support/MyApp")
prefs?.localStorageEnabled = true
```

But I get an error:

> Use of undeclared type WebPreferences

I pay attention to your comments, greetings and many thanks in advance.

I update my question.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webView: WebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.loadUrl( string: "www.google.com")
    }

    class WebView: WKWebView{
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            if let _view = UIView(coder: coder){
                super.init(frame: _view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
                autoresizingMask = _view.autoresizingMask

            }else{
            return nil
            }
        }

        func loadUrl(string: String){
            if let url = URL(string: string ) {
                load(URLRequest(url: url))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing `WebKit`?

Comment: Yes, but webpreferences is for macOS?

Comment: Yes, for older versions of macOS. The class for iOS seems to be called `WKPreferences`.

Comment: The most recent documentation seems to state that localStorage is enabled by default on `UIWebView`s. You might want to show your code so people can find other issues.

Comment: Have you tried using localStorage? Did it not work? Are you sure that your error is localStorage-related?

Comment: In android that was the problem, but in swift I'm just starting to program, the code I currently have is one of all the tests I've been performing.

Comment: You should probably test some more possibilities before assuming it's localStorage. As I've said, iOS `WebView`s have localStorage enabled by default.